# better phrase than "I felt rewarded"

Tags: phrase-usage

According to Google ngram viewer, "I felt rewarded" is not frequently used. What would be a better to way phrase this?

For example, I want to say " I felt very rewarded when I saw my students performing well on their exams"

Thank you.

Comment: I have *absolutely* no hesitation using *I felt rewarded...* Why would I opt for anything else when the phrase conveys what I want to say? It might be not *that* frequent, but it is fairly usable.

Answer (score 3):

I ran several different versions of different phrases through Google Books Ngram Viewer, and came up with [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+felt+rewarded%2CI+felt+gratified%2CI+felt+satisfied%2CI+was+gratified%2CI+was+satisifed%2CI+felt+grateful%2CI+was+grateful%2C+I+felt+contented%2C+I+was+contented%2C+I+felt+fulfilled%2C+I+was+fulfilled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20rewarded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20gratified%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20satisfied%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20gratified%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20grateful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20grateful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20contented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20contented%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20felt%20fulfilled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20was%20fulfilled%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

Assuming that you want to base word choice on this tool, and that you're looking for something that has relatively more usage, it appears that the most common synonymous phrase is **I was grateful**.

In which case, your example sentence could be rephrased as:

> I was grateful to see my students performing well on their exams.

I will note, however, that **grateful** need not always mean the same thing as **rewarded**. (The same is true of any other synonymous phrase.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is much wrong with "I felt rewarded", but here are some alternatives you might consider:

- I felt content
- I had a feeling of satisfaction
- I felt tremendously fulfilled.

There you have three different words and phrased three different ways. They could all be used interchangeably (almost), for example you could use *content*, *contented*, or speak of *a feeling of contentment*.

Hope this helps!